# How to return value in a recursively for loop function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, recursion, search

Here's the code.

```
var temp = [
    { 
    slugs: ['men'], 
    children: [
      { slugs: ['men', 'tops'], children: [
        { slugs: ['men', 'tops', 'shirts'] },
        { slugs: ['men', 'tops', 'swe'] }
      ] },
      {
        slugs: ['men', 'bottoms'], children: [
          { slugs: ['men', 'bottoms', 'pants'] },
          { slugs: ['men', 'bottoms', 'under'] }
        ]
      }
    ] 
  },
  {
    slugs: ['women'], 
    children: [
      { slugs: ['women', 'tops'], children: [
        { slugs: ['women', 'tops', 'shirts'] },
        { slugs: ['women', 'tops', 'swe'] }
      ] },
      {
        slugs: ['women', 'bottoms'], children: [
          { slugs: ['women', 'bottoms', 'pants'] },
          { slugs: ['women', 'bottoms', 'under'] }
        ]
      }
    ] 
  }
]

function matchTreeObj (tree, location) {
  if (_.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for(let i=0;i<tree.length;i++){
        matchTreeObj(tree[i], location)
    }
  }
  if (tree.slugs && (tree.slugs.join('/') === location)) {
    console.log(tree)
    return tree
  } else if (tree.children && tree.children.length > 0) {
    matchTreeObj(tree.children, location)
  }
}
const aaa = matchTreeObj(temp, 'men/tops')

console.log('from log', aaa)
```

It's using lodash and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moshe444/vsnebjuf/) is here.
The code basically ouputs the object chunk which its `slugs` value matches the location parameter.
I could get the console log works properly. But I can not get the returned data. (I already tried to return the function where I use it recursively, and still not work.)
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the array in the `for` loop, check the output of calling `matchTreeObj` - if it's truthy, return it:

```
for(let i=0;i<tree.length;i++){
  const result = matchTreeObj(tree[i], location)
  if (result) return result;
}
```

Also return the recursive call in the lower `else if`:

```
} else if (tree.children && tree.children.length > 0) {
  return matchTreeObj(tree.children, location)
}
```

```js
var temp = [
 { 
   slugs: ['men'], 
    children: [
      { slugs: ['men', 'tops'], children: [
        { slugs: ['men', 'tops', 'shirts'] },
        { slugs: ['men', 'tops', 'swe'] }
      ] },
      {
        slugs: ['men', 'bottoms'], children: [
          { slugs: ['men', 'bottoms', 'pants'] },
          { slugs: ['men', 'bottoms', 'under'] }
        ]
      }
    ] 
  },
  {
   slugs: ['women'], 
    children: [
      { slugs: ['women', 'tops'], children: [
        { slugs: ['women', 'tops', 'shirts'] },
        { slugs: ['women', 'tops', 'swe'] }
      ] },
      {
        slugs: ['women', 'bottoms'], children: [
          { slugs: ['women', 'bottoms', 'pants'] },
          { slugs: ['women', 'bottoms', 'under'] }
        ]
      }
    ] 
  }
]

function matchTreeObj (tree, location) {
  if (_.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for(let i=0;i<tree.length;i++){
     const result = matchTreeObj(tree[i], location)
      if (result) return result;
    }
  }
  if (tree.slugs && (tree.slugs.join('/') === location)) {
    return tree
    } else if (tree.children && tree.children.length > 0) {
      return matchTreeObj(tree.children, location)
    }
}
const aaa = matchTreeObj(temp, 'men/tops')

console.log('from log', aaa)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

The logic might be easier to grasp at a glance if you separated out the array iteration and the object testing, though, and no need for a big library to accomplish this:

```js
var temp=[{slugs:['men'],children:[{slugs:['men','tops'],children:[{slugs:['men','tops','shirts']},{slugs:['men','tops','swe']}]},{slugs:['men','bottoms'],children:[{slugs:['men','bottoms','pants']},{slugs:['men','bottoms','under']}]}]},{slugs:['women'],children:[{slugs:['women','tops'],children:[{slugs:['women','tops','shirts']},{slugs:['women','tops','swe']}]},{slugs:['women','bottoms'],children:[{slugs:['women','bottoms','pants']},{slugs:['women','bottoms','under']}]}]}];

function matchArr(arr, location) {
  for (const item of arr) {
    const result = matchItem(item, location);
    if (result) return result;
  }
}
function matchItem(item, location) {
  if (item.slugs.join('/') === location) {
    return item;
  } else if (item.children) {
    return matchArr(item.children, location);
  }
}
const output = matchArr(temp, 'men/tops')
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice opportunity to learn about [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) – In mathematics and computer science, mutual recursion is a form of recursion where two mathematical or computational objects, such as functions or data types, are defined in terms of each other. Mutual recursion is very common in functional programming and in some problem domains, such as recursive descent parsers, where the data types are naturally mutually recursive –

```
type node =
  { slugs : string array
  , children : node array
  }
```

Each node has a *children* property which is an array of nodes, each of which have a *children* property containing even more nodes. So there you have it, a recursive data structure and a good time to apply a mutual recursion technique.

Below, `match` calls `match1`, which in turn calls `match`. Both functions are written using a pure expression. No `for` loop is necessary as `for` is a statement, relies on a side effect, and is used in imperative style. Functional stye avoids side effects and so favors recursion in place of `for` loops –

```
const None =
  Symbol ()

const EmptyNode =
  { slugs: []
  , children: []
  }

const match1 = (s = "", node = EmptyNode) =>
  node.slugs .join ('/') === s
    ? node
    : match (s, node.children)

const match = (s = "", [ node = None, ...rest ] = []) =>
  node === None
    ? undefined
    : match1 (s, node) || match (s, rest)

console .log
  ( match ("men/tops", data)       // { slugs: [ men, tops ], ... }
  , match ("women/bottoms", data)  // { slugs: [ women, bottoms ], ... }
  , match ("cat/dog", data)        // undefined
  )
```

A small adaptation allows us to collect *all* results instead of stopping after the *first* match -

```
const EmptyNode =
  { slugs: []
  , children: []
  }

const match1 = (s = "", node = EmptyNode) =>
  node.slugs .join ('/') === s
    ? [ node, ...match (s, node.children) ]
    : match (s, node.children)

const match = (s = "", nodes = []) =>
  nodes .flatMap (x => match1 (s, x))

console .log
  ( match ("men/tops", data) // [ ... all matches ... ]
  , match ("cat/dog", data)  // []
  )
```

Hey look, we *returned a value* without even using `return`. Thanks, functional style.